# How to include in our repository Infrastructure as Code using Visual Studio

Tags: azure, continuous-deployment, azure-resource-manager, octopus-deploy

We are trying to implement a continuous deployment pipeline and we would like to create our resources from Azure Resource Templates.

**Questions**

1.What kind of a project should we choose?

2.How should we integrate  it with Octopus ?

3.How should we trigger the infrastructure setup process ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I.Using this template is a progress in the right direction.**
[image]

**II.Octopus calls Azure API s so it is much better to provide a deployment package and in case needed deploy it using VS.**

[image]

[image]

**III.Starting Continuous Deployment with Push makes the process easier as the locus of control is better.**